# When writing an override method, why calling another superclass method is allowed in Java?

Tags: java

Today I unintentionally called wrong overloaded super method in child class:

```
public class Test {
    public static class A {
        void foo(int p) {
            // Do something...
        }

        void foo() {
            foo(-1);
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        @Override
        void foo(int p) {
            super.foo(); // Intended to call super.foo(p), but lost a parameter here
            // Do something more...
        }
    }
}
```

When running this program, it stood for a while, then shouted at me with a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.
I found the problem and fixed it, but I can't understand why this is allowed.

Futhermore, I changed the `super.foo();` call to `super.equals("");`, the code still gets compiled and runs successfully.

So why super call is allowed to call some other methods? I cannot imagine such a use case, and cannot find any useful information by googling around. So I think this should be treated as an error maybe?

Comment: I don't see why this should not be allowed. Why do you think this should not be allowed?

Comment: if your classes are marked as static can you really inherit one from the other? I suspect not

Comment: @Sahuagin why shouldn´t you be able to do so? `static` inner classes are just not bound to the outer instance but don´t deny inheritance

Comment: @Axel you see, it's causing problem here and I think it should be detected in compile time to avoid such unintentional problems. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: @KevinEsche k thanks, not used to that concept

Comment: @Sahuagin I'm just making a test case and don't want to create two files, so I use two static inner classes here.

Comment: @notsyncing why do you think so? Why should a call to a `super` method be restricted here? What if it´s part of the implemenation do call a `super` before starting the overloaded implentation? Also it´s the same as just calling `foo()` in this case, the `super` is unnecessary here as `foo()` isn´t overriden by `B`.

Comment: it is your responsibility as the programmer to design an interface of your classes that avoids such problems. More effort in good naming is one way to go. the other is *favor composition over inheritance*

Comment: @notsyncing: If all an overridden methods could do was call its super implementation, then what point would there be to override it in the first place? Why override foo(int p) if all it does is call super.foo(int p)?

Comment: @911DidBush I'm just making a test case here, I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: In my 16 years as a Java programmer I cannot remember having needed to call a different method in the superclass explicitly (but often a different method in the same class, sometimes *implemented* in the superclass). And as the question shows, it being allowed can lead to mistakes. So I get the point. On the other hand, for compatibility I’m sure it won’t be disallowed in any future Java version.

Comment: @KevinEsche Yes I've not considered this situation, but in your case, ```super``` seems to be unnecessary? I think ```super``` should be an explicit indicator for "I want to call the super method", so if every overloaded implementations need to call a common method, just call it without ```super```.

Comment: @notsyncing that´s true and that´s why i said `in this case`. yeah, it would change once you override `foo()`, but as it´s not the `case` leaving out the `super` or including it would call the same implementation currently.

Comment: FWIW, Java is more restrictive than C++, probably the main inspiration for the super call. In C++ you may call a method in *any* class up the inheritance chain (`extends` chain). Always seemed dangerous to me. In Java you can at least only call the immediate superclass, not its superclasses. A step in the right direction IMHO, though opinions may differ.

Comment: @OleV.V. but in java, the ```super``` call still can access the superclass of superclass, thus climbing the inheritance chain, e.g. I can call ```super.equals()``` in class ```B```, which defined in ```Object``` supers ```A```. Maybe you mean _multiple inheritance_ which c++ supports?

Comment: Nope, @notsyncing, I didn’t mean to refer to multiple inheritance. In C++ I can bypass any number of implementstions of `equals()` (for the sake of the example) in my call to `Object.equals()`. But we’re digressing.

Comment: @OleV.V. understood. Seems really dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why super call is allowed to call some other methods?

Because your code may need to do that. It's no different, really, from a method calling other methods defined by the same class. Remember that the superclass's methods are part of the current instance. Inheritance is massively tightly-coupled. So any non-`private` member of the superclass can be used, as it's part of the instance and not hidden from the subclass. (`private` members are still part of the instance, but are hidden from the subclass unless you [ab]use reflection to expose them.)

It's worth noting that this doesn't have anything to do with these being nested classes; it's true for top-level classes as well.

Comment: so ```super``` is just like ```this``` but for its superclass?

Comment: @notsyncing: Pretty much. `super` is just like `this` but skipping any overrides in the current class.

Comment: @TJCrowder I always treated it as an explicit indicator of "I want to call the super method", which seems wrong now. Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: @notsyncing: Depends on what you mean by "super method." `super.foo()` *does* mean "call the superclass's version of `foo`" regardless of where in the subclass you call it (in `foo`, in `bar`, in a constructor, etc.). So in that sense it means just what you said. If you mean "super method" as "the super version of *the calling* method," then no, that's not what it is. :-)